# Do we lose messages, if limit in SQS is exceeded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

In AWS SQS console,

I have created **Standard SQS Queue** and configured as following:

```
Message retention period: 4 hours
Default visibility timeout: 1 hour
Receive message wait time: 0 seconds
Delivery Delay: 0 seconds
```

Poll settings as following:

```
Polling Duration: 60 seconds
Maximum message count: 500
```

But, What if the count of messages sent to the queue is 1500?

There's a lambda that's processing the messages every half an hour and deleting the (read) SQS messages.

Will other 1000 messages get lost or will they get into SQS whenever another messages in SQS are getting deleted?

Comment: Why is your Lambda function only running every 30 minutes? You can configure the SQS queue to trigger the Lambda function as soon as a message arrives, so they can be processed much sooner rather than in half-hourly batches.

Comment: Right, Let me give you an example. Let us think that there will be 700 messages entering SQS queue every half an hour, why do we need our lambda to run 700*48 (33600) times a day. Instead we can code our lambda in such a way that it can read 700 messages from SQS in a single run. In this case, lambda runs only 48 times a day.

Comment: Rather than saying "why do we need our lambda to run 33600 times a day", you should be asking "why do we _not_ want it to run 33600 times a day". Lambda functions are charged based upon the execution duration, so it should incur similar costs in both scenarios. The benefit is that messages are processed immediately, rather than waiting for batches and there is less risk of hitting timeout errors for large batches. The Lambda function can also run in parallel. Up to 10 messages can be provided to the Lambda function for each execution, if multiple messages are available in the queue.

Comment: Good to know that. But, For some reason, SQS messages stay in-flight whenever I try to add SQS as trigger to lambda. Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: When triggering an AWS Lambda function from an Amazon SQS queue, the messages will be passed-in via the `events` variable. The Lambda function **should not** call Amazon SQS itself to retrieve any messages or delete any messages. I suspect that your existing Lambda function calls SQS directly, so it will need a coding change to handle the incoming messages that are provided. (It actually makes the code simpler!) For some examples, see: [Sample Amazon SQS function code - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-create-package.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an **unlimited** number of messages.

So they will not get deleted from your SQS. Instead they will be send to your lambda as a second batch.

Comment: So, It shouldn't be a problem, Even if I set the max message count to 500. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack This is batch size for lambda, not max count of sqs.

Comment: No, It is not SQS that is triggering lambda, It is cloudwatch's eventbridge.